# I need some help regarding §8/5 in the spec

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, trailing-return-type

§8/5:

> The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* in a *trailing-return-type*
>   appertains to the indicated return type. The *type-id* in a
>   *trailing-return-type* includes the longest possible sequence of *abstract-declarator*s. [ Note: This resolves the ambiguous binding of array and function declarators. [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto f()->int(*)[4]; // function returning a pointer to array[4] of int
>                      // not function returning array[4] of pointer to int
> ```
>
> —end example ] —end note ]

The "*type-id* in a *trailing-return-type*" doesn't make sense to me, simply because a *trailing-return-type* doesn't contain a *type-id* according to the grammar.

I also don't understand the "ambiguous binding" of array and function declaration. As far as I can understand

```
auto f() -> int*[4]; // function returning an array of 4 pointers to int
auto f() -> int(*)[4]; // function returning a pointer to an array of 4 ints
```

Comment: Can you please ask a question?

Comment: Presumably the *type-id* refers to the whole thing after the `->`, since a *trailing-type-specifier-seq* generates/is a subset of *type-specifier-seq* (looking at C++11 §7.1.6/1).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think that's right. It is rather sloppy writing, though.

Comment: There used to be a _type-id_ in the grammar of trailing return type. [N2927](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf) changed that part of the grammar, and moved the paragraph you cited from §8.3.5/3 to §8/5, but did not change the wording (which is presumably an oversight).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int *f();
```

Declares a function of `()` returning pointer to `int`.

```
int *f()[4];
```

Declares a function of `()` returning array of 4 pointers to `int`. Note that this is ill-formed.

```
int (*f())[4];
```

Declares a function of `()` returning pointer to array of 4 `int`.

Now, in

```
  auto f() -> int(*)[4]
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

What the rule resolves is whether `[4]` is part of the *trailing-return-type*, and hence part of the the function declarator. If `[4]` is part of the *trailing-return-type*, then the above declaration declares a function of `()` returning pointer to array of 4 `int`.

If not, then `[4]` would form an array declarator that is not part of the function declarator, and the parse would be governed by [dcl.array]/p1:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> ```
> D1 [ constant-expression_opt ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is
>   “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`” [..., if] the value of the
>   constant expression is `N`, [...] the type of the identifier of `D` is
>   “*derived-declarator-type-list* array of `N` `T`”.

and since `auto f()-> int (*)` declares `f` as "function of `()` returning pointer to `int`", substitution tells us that this would declare a function returning an array of 4 pointers to `int`, just like `int *f()[4];`.

Comment: According to the grammar in [dcl.decl]p4, there must be a `noptr-declarator` on the left side of this `[4]`, but it seems that `f() -> int(*)` does not qualify as a `noptr-declarator`.

Comment: ... In [N2541](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2541.htm), `f() -> int(*)` qualifies as a `direct-declarator`, which can appear on the left of `[4]`, so disambiguating is necessary. But the grammar of declarators has undergone quite a few changes since then. I wonder whether the ambiguity has been silently removed by one of these changes.